# cloning CENTOS server (image) to DVD burner / External Hard Disk or over the network

Tags: centos

I have centos server.
I would like to take the server and install it to another empty server.
what is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Over a network

```
dd if=/dev/hda | ssh username@backupserver.fqdn \
"dd of=/directory_of_backups_on_ssh_server/backupfile.iso"
```

Modify to suit.

Stolen from: http://karlherrick.com/dev/2008/09/12/dd-backups-over-ssh/

Comment: how do I restore the iso file to a new server?

Comment: Do you have physical access, or network access?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look and see if Clonezilla may work for you:

http://clonezilla.org/

Some restrictions depending on if you have software RAID or not and a few others. Definitely good to look into though.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any custom code (ie everything was installed using yum), you can install centos on a new box, and then install everything in /var/log/rpmpkgs.

After that's done, copy over your config files & ssh key form /etc, then your data.

Change the IP of your old server to an unused one, bounce the new server, make sure it comes up with the right IP, and check everything.

It takes a few steps this way, but it's all very straightforward.